# How to load a mp3 file from internal storage? (air for android)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm working on a mobile project which needs to play a mp3 from internal storage.

My code:

```
Var r:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/storage/emulated/0/mysound.mp3");

Var s:Sound = new Sound (r);
S.play();
```

But the path is not correct.
What is the path of internal storage?

edited: can someone give me a certain directory on android devices??

Comment: Have you at least tried searching Google? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

Comment: I need a special location for android devices that i can access the mp3 file later.